# python logging based on some condition

Tags: python

i am using python logging module to perfrom lots of logging in my application. it works fine when i use different handlers to log to `stdout` and `file`. my usecase is:
on local testing log to stdout while on production deployment log to file insted of stdout.

so i was lokking for some condition based log (ex; based on some environment variable value) if its local log to stdout otherwise file.

here is how i can achieve using two handlers:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("logging")
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(name)s |  %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logFilePath = "my.log"
file_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename = logFilePath, when = 'midnight', backupCount = 30)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

Comment: You can do this with the `os` package to read enviroment variables and an `if` condition. No need for extra packages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add some code to my initial commment:

```
import os
logger = logging.getLogger("logging")
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(name)s |  %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

if os.getenv("ENV_VAR_YOU_WANT"):
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

else:
    logFilePath = "my.log"
    handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename = logFilePath, when = 'midnight', backupCount = 30)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: but suppose at some place i need to log. if i call `log.info()` it works fine but when i call `log.debug()` nothing is printed on stdout. what should i call excatly?. ineed a single methd call which would print to stdout or file based on set env variable

Comment: That is because in the `stdout` logger you have set the log level to `INFO` in instance of `DEBUG`.  Change `handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)` to `handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` and it will work.

Comment: suppose i have set the env variable and i verifed it by echoing it. now at some point in my codebase i would like to perform a log.what should i call. log.info() or log.debug()?

Comment: That depends on the importance of that log message. It's up to you to decide which one do you want to use in each occasion.